# Git log listing commits specific to a date

Tags: git, selection, commit

I have been working with Git for a few months and have been slowly automating our processes so we don't have to do so much manual work to deploy our changes.

I have been working with Git's --since option in which from what I can tell would work with this exact syntax: --since={2014-02-03}

The problem is that it never lists all of the commits on that date forward.  It lists most but not all.  And, from what I can tell it misses the oldest commit on that day.  Sometimes 2 or 3 but the last one appears to be consistent.

I also merged in some commits from another repo and things got a little hosed up from that as well.  My theory was that the selection is made based on hashes that were assigned on 2 different repos and therefore fell in the range of what I was selecting.  I was using the hash to select a range.  Which I've also had trouble with.

My goal is to execute a log command that ultimately gives me the commits that haven't been deployed.  I am using shell script to extract the files and produce a deployable directory which is then copied to the target servers and then to their web roots.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One problem with `--since` and `--until` (or their synonyms) is time zone stuff.  The date stored in the commit is in UTC, but shown in local time:

```
author ... 1385598279 -0700

$ date -r 1385598279
Wed Nov 27 17:24:39 MST 2013
$ TZ=UTC date -r 1385598279
Thu Nov 28 00:24:39 UTC 2013
```

So, what day *is* 1385598279?  The 27th, or the 28th?  Depends whether I'm in Salt Lake City, London, or somewhere else.

(There are also two 2:30 AMs on one day of the year, and no 2:30 AMs on another day.)

You would probably be better off saving the SHA-1 for each deployed version.  The SHA-1 is guaranteed to be unique, and will identify the exact version.  Given two commit SHA-1s you can tell exactly what changed between them by running `git diff` on those.

Comment: Here's what I get from the above command:  date -r 1385598279
Wed Nov 27 18:24:39 CST 2013  I am in CST time zone.  I don't include the time with it.  I wonder if that is the problem?  I just use the date the way I indicated above.  It should work as long as the day portion matches.